# Update div with the result of an Ajax-call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to display the response of the ajax function below to a div in the dom (update div). How is this to be done without using heavy plugins.

```
url: 'http://dowmian.com/xs1/getcam.php',
type: 'GET',
data: {id: <?php echo $cam_id; ?>},
success: function(responseText){
},
error: function(responseText){
}
```

Comment: Please tag questions like this with javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the return value of your `getcam.php` function, but you're probably looking for the `html()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dowmian.com/xs1/getcam.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {id: <?php echo $cam_id; ?>},
    success: function(responseText){
        $('#update-div').html(responseText);
    },
    error: function(responseText){
    }
});
```

If you want to append the `#update-div` dynamically, as in just before the ajax-call, you can do this with `append()`:

```
$('.container').append($('<div/>').attr('id','update-div'));
```

**References**:

- [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: would it be possible to append the div update_div before returning the responsetext?

Comment: Sure it would. You could add it just before the ajax call, by calling $('.container').append($('<div/>').attr('id','update-div'));

Or simply add it in plain html. Answer updated!

Answer (score 1):

Inside success, do this:

```
success: function(responseText) {
    $("#target").text(responseText);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the empty 'success' handler function you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
success: function(responseText) {
    $("#update-div").text(responseText.d);
},
```

You can get more info from [here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)