# Understanding Ajax requests to update page content when SQL Query Response changes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xhtml

I am writing a page update which works with PHP to read a SQL database the page echo's the contents in a div section 'track_data'. yet it doesn't do this update idk

I have JavaScript script which I dont really fully understand and hopeful someone could explain its principally the check response section I think is failing ? :

in my PHP page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function InitReload() {

    new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('track_data', 'fetch_sql.php', {
      method: 'get', frequency: 60, decay: 1});
}
</script>
```

Thanks for looking and hopefully someone undersstands this and can put a smile on my face  for the second time today :)

**Steps to fix**
Thanks for the suggestions of syntax errors. I haven't really got very far with this here are the changes you suggested which I have changed but I still think there is something wrong with last function as it doesn't update  div section.

**Code in JS file**

```
// Start Clock refresh

// uses new new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater( 
// in main fetch file to trigger the auto update of the page.
// Written by Denise Rose

var gUpdateDiv;
var gContentURL;
var gcheckInterval;
var gcheckURL = "";
var gCurrentCheck  ="";

_fetchUpdater('track_data','/fetch_sql.php','/fetch_sql.php',8000);


function _fetchUpdater(updateDiv,contentURL,checkURL,checkInterval)
{
    gUpdateDiv = updateDiv;
    gContentURL = contentURL;
    gcheckInterval = checkInterval;
    gcheckURL = checkURL;
    
    setTimeout('check();',gCheckInterval);
}

//Called by _fetchUpdater every (n) seconds  determins if content should be updated.
function check()
{
    new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl,{method:'get', onSuccess:'checkResponse'});
    setTimeout('check();',gCheckInterval);
}

// looks for the response and determines if the div should be updated. 
function checkResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;
    if(gCurrentCheck != content) {
      gCurrentCheck = content;
      new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl, {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML = t.responseText; /*t.response.json()*/}
        
      }); 
    }
}
```

**This is the bit I dont understand**

```
function checkResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;

    if(gCurrentCheck != content) {
      gCurrentCheck = content;
      new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl, {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML = t.response.json();/*t.responseText;*/}
        
      }); 
    }
}
```

**Method and Issues**
What is transport here and what is t?  if it stores the contents of the body text from the second in gCurrentCheck and compares to transport version content then why doesn't it update if its different please which it is if the SQL has created a different page?

I did find this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxtransport/

**First Answer not using Ajax**
I was given a neat and JS version  as an answer, which is not really what I was looking for. I was hopeful to get the one working with one with Ajax but I appreciate your efforts is very kind. I just really wanted to send a refresh to the div area so that the PHP rebuilt the page from the SQL.

I might have been missing the MIT javascript http://www.prototypejs.org/ lol but I dont think it was.

**Just to help:**
AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files. ... Make requests to the server without reloading the page.

**Researching**
I found this [Update div with the result of an Ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362235/update-div-with-the-result-of-an-ajax-call) but it did not really explain as the OP was using PHP like me not HTML. The answer was given:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dowmian.com/xs1/getcam.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {id: <?php echo $cam_id; ?>},
    success: function(responseText){
        $('#update-div').html(responseText);
    },
    error: function(responseText){
    }
});
```

I dont think above it answered posters question or mine as ajax is a server based push how is this relevant? as if its PHP driven the  needs a refresh at server to refresh the contents  not to provide new html. It is this **refresh** I am not interested in to re-copy PHP code elsewhere in JS as its already in my PHP. Does that make more sense?

**Update**
I did find a bracket missing and a set of single quotes inserted by editor. Which I have updated above but there was no significant change.
Cheers Nicolas . I am still hopeful that someone knows about Ajax as it sits underneath these technologies. I have a server side PHP file that I was hoping to use AJAX to pull just the PHP from the section  it was pointing to an gUpdateDiv . As its derived from the server and created on the fly from SQL.  I dont see how your answer would help push this data back in to the  from the server . The $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML was supposed to be acted upon not the whole page . What I am unsure of is how a trigger from this can update timer just this $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML . I am also not aware if a server based refresh would do this or if the transport id provided from the file  would be able to deliver just that . I think I am missing something a vital part that I dont have or have grasped yet. The reason there is two timers is effectively it checks the same file at a different point in time as its created by PHP it might be different from the first if it is i.e. the SQL data has changed, I want this to update this $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML with the data which it compared it to the second 'Get' in the second request. It sounds,  simple in practice but have got stuck comparing two versions and insuring second version gets used .

**Further update** placing an alert in the Javascript file did not pop up like it does here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert however the same alert in the initiating PHP worked fine and created the alert.  called the same function from the main PHP nd the alert occurred so the JavaScript is running next visit F12 on the page to see if there is any warnings or errors. Ok after adding JQuery which I thought I had added this started working however It is not doing what i Expected it to do. As the  contained both text and graphics created by PHP I expected this all to be updated The graphics are not the text is any ideas? .

Further to the image problems I placed an extra line to update the image however  I used this too **in PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//initpage() ;
function updateArtworkDisplay() {
        document.querySelector('#np_track_artwork').src = 'images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png?' + new Date().getTime();
    }
</Script>
```

**But it didnt work to update the image in php?**

`<div id='outer_img'><img id='#np_track_artwork' src='/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png' alt='Playing track artwork' width='200' height='200'></div>`

**in js change**

```
/ looks for the response and determines if the div should be updated. 
function checkResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;
    if(gCurrentCheck != content) {
      gCurrentCheck = content;
      new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl, {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML = t.responseText; /*t.response.json()*/}
        
        
      }); 
      updateArtworkDisplay(); // fire up the redraw in php file.
    }
}
```

**Nearly there** it does almost what it needs to apart from the redraw which is not happening

```
// Start Clock refresh

// uses new new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater( 
// in main fetch file to trigger the auto update of the page.
// Written by Denise Rose

var gUpdateDiv="";
var gContentURL="";
var gcheckInterval=0;
var gcheckURL = "";
var gCurrentCheck  ="";





_fetchUpdater('track_data','/fetch_sql.php','/fetch_sql.php',8000);


function _fetchUpdater(updateDiv,contentURL,checkURL,checkInterval)
{
    gUpdateDiv = updateDiv;
    gContentURL = contentURL;
    gcheckInterval = checkInterval;
    gCheckURL = checkURL;
    
    setTimeout('check();',gcheckInterval);
}

//Called by _fetchUpdater every (n) seconds  determins if content should be updated.
function check()
{
   new Ajax.Request(gCheckURL,{method:'get',  onSuccess:'CheckResponse()'});
   setTimeout('check();',gcheckInterval);
}

// looks for the response and determines if the div should be updated. 
function checkResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;
    if(gCurrentCheck != content) {
       
      gCurrentCheck = content;
       
      new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl, {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML = t.responseText; /*t.response.json()*/}
        
        
      });
      
      $time = new Date().getTime();
      new Ajax.Request('outer_img', {method: 'get',onSuccess:function s() { 
         $('outer_img').innerHTML = "<img id='#np_track_artwork' src='/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png?t='"+$time+" alt='Playing track artwork' width='200' height='200'>"}
          
      });
           
    }
}
```

Comment: there are a couple of syntactial errors in your script, it cannot work like that. Check your browser console first

Comment: One is `gcheck Interval = checkInterval;` That space between `gcheck` and `Interval`

Comment: the first `setTimeout` is missing a opening parenthesis, in the second there are mismatched single quotations

Answer (score 0):

GIVEN UP WITH THIS PLEASE DELETE MY PERSONAL INFORMATION AND POSTSript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: @virtualKitten AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. There is not really an AJAX answer.  The library that you're using is Javascript. If you want to render the HTML server-side and serve it to the client. You can just swap response.json() with response.text() and append it to the innerHTML. The references that I posted have it all there. The purpose of the answer is to help you, not solve directly the problem based on a 3rd party JS library. Cheers.

Comment: @virtualKitten do you call the function initPage(); somewhere? Declaring it only, won't trigger it.